# C++ error — No match for operator =

Tags: c++, arrays, casting, operands

```
class RLE_v1
{
    struct header
    {
        char sig[4];
        int fileSize;
        unsigned char fileNameLength;
        std::string fileName;
    } m_Header;

    RLE<char> m_Data;

public:
    void CreateArchive(const std::string& source)
    {
        std::ifstream::pos_type size;
        char* memblock;
        std::ifstream file (source, std::ios::in|std::ios::binary|std::ios::ate);
        if (file.is_open())
        {
            size = file.tellg();
            memblock = new char [static_cast<unsigned int>(size)];
            file.seekg (0, std::ios::beg);
            file.read (memblock, size);
            file.close();
            //
            // trying to make assignment to m_Data here.
            //
            delete[] memblock;
        }
    }

    void ExtractArchive(const std::string& source);
};
```

I'm trying to copy the data in the "memblock" char array into the variable  m_Data, but when I try to do it I get the error that `no match for operator "=" matches these operands`. I have no idea how to make them equal, because `m_Data` is already of type `char`.

This is the RLE class that has the variable m_Data as a mem

```
template <typename T>
struct RLE
{

    T* m_Data;  // Memory which stores either compressed or decompressed data
    int m_Size; // Number of elements of type T that data is pointing to

    RLE()
        : m_Data(nullptr)
        , m_Size(0)
    { }

    ~RLE()
    {
        delete m_Data;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've shown everything except the actual line that produces the error.

But what I see is this.  You have a class that has the member:

```
RLE<char> m_Data;
```

After template expansion, that struct will have the member:

```
char *m_Data;
```

You say there is no `operator=` when you assign `memblock` to `m_Data`.  So I can only conclude that you are doing this:

```
m_Data = memblock;
```

Where you should *actually* be doing this:

```
m_Data.m_Data = memblock;
m_Data.m_Size = size;
```

Instead of directly operating on a struct's internals, you might be better off making a function:

```
template <typename T>
void RLE<T>::Alloc( size_t size )
{
    if( m_Data != nullptr ) delete [] m_Data;
    m_Data = new T [size];
    m_Size = size;
}
```

Comment: why should it be m.Data.m_Data? sorry i'm a little bit confused

Comment: and yes i was trying to do m_data = memblock; and the line that produces the error is where i said "i tried to copy the data..." sorry.

Comment: +1 I'm guessing saving off that pointer into the `RLE<char>` is probably going to be worthless if it is followed up immediately by `delete[] memblock`. And following up your Alloc suggestion, even more home: `RLE<T>::ReadStream(ifstream& inf, size_t size)` may equally come in handy.

Comment: Haha good point @WhozCraig - Hope you're listening, user1665569.  After you copy a pointer with the intention of passing ownership to someone else, don't then go and delete it.  Copying pointers doesn't duplicate the memory.  If you delete your memory, all pointers to that memory become worthless.

Comment: once i fill up memblock i'm trying to store it into the variable m_data so i can use m-Data it for compression or decompression...

Comment: @user1665569 Your problem is more to do with your choice of variable names.  If you hadn't made an instance of `RLE<char>` called `m_Data` which contains a `char*` variable called `m_Data` you wouldn't be half as confused as you are now.

Comment: @user1665569 paddy has both the right answer, and some good suggestions, and i'll leave this little tryst with one more: use a [`std::vector<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for this, and a LOT of problems go away.

Comment: OOH..thank you @paddy. This is not my code. The teacher gave it to us as a lab, and I got really lost on that part.

Comment: thank you both @WhozCraig and paddy. you two have been truly useful